# OAuth - Separating Auth Server and Resource server returns invalid token when accessing protected resource

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

1. I have a Restful example which uses **Spring Security** and **OAuth2** and it works well. Basically, I can get an `access_token` and use that `access_token` to access protected resources. Similar example here: [Securing Restful Web Services with Spring Security and OAuth](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html)
2. I have changed that example by adding `customUserAuthenticationProvider` to authenticate against **Mysql** via **Hibernate**. Like what described in this example: [spring4-rest-oauth2](https://github.com/hcadavid/spring4-rest-oauth2)
3. I replaced `InMemoryTokenStore` by `JdbcTokenStore`. MySQL schema for `oauth_access_token` table looks like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `oauth_access_token` (
   `token_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `token` blob,
   `authentication_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `user_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `client_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `authentication` blob,
   `refresh_token` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
   `access_token_validity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `refresh_token_validity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
4. No problem so far. Every thing works fine. Every time I log in there will be a row added to `oauth_access_token` table (I can use MySQL workbench to view blob column (token)). I can use this access token to access protected source without any issues.
5. Now, I run 2 instances of Jetty each has its own port, i.e **8080** and **8888**. Each instance has identical war file. I login on the first instance to get the `access_token` and after that I use this access_token to access protected resource from the second instance. However, it always return `401 error: Invalid access token`.

If I use this `access_token` to access resource in the first instance it run well.

Another weird observation is that if I try to access resource from the second instance, `access_token` in the `oauth_access_token` will be deleted. I have to re-login to have this row inserted to the table again.

6. This is `springSecurity.xml` file I used for both instances:
   [SpringSecurity](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/63702128/stackoverflow/springSecurity.xml)

**My question are:**
- Have anyone run into the issues similar to mine? I know that using JdbcTokenStore is somehow straightforward but I don't know why it happened to my case.
- How to fix this?
Any comments, pointers, suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify why I really need to separate Auth and Resource server. The reason is to scale the application to more than one single server. In that case, I can have many Resource servers and one central Auth server.

I am also thinking about an alternative in case this bug could not be fixed that I will deploy multiple instances of the same combined war (authorization and resource) and place them behind an nginx. By using a sticky session approach, it can offer a real scaling, i.e users get an access token and use that token to access resource in the same instance.

Comment: It seems there is some kind of caching or maybe you just have two separate databases? MySQL isn't the best solution for distributed databases - (http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-vs-couchdb.html)

Comment: @JanekOlszak Thanks for your comments. Indeed, both of the instances are running on the same computer. They are just in different ports so they are using the same database I am sure (dataSource is pointing to the same db). For caching reason I don't think it matters here because I restart jetty over again and again.

Comment: Maybe you don't finish a transation? That would explain why one instance sees the changes and the other doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean database transaction? Indeed, after login a row inserted into access token table in db, thus I think the transation was completed. The weird thing is whenever I try access resource from the other instance, that row containing access_token is removed from db.