# Can Authorization Server and Resource Server be merged in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement an OAuth2 provider for my web service.

It seems easier to implement the Authentication Server together with the Resource Server. The specification doesn't say anything about the communication between them.

Does anybody see a reason not to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a post yesterday regarding this issue. I hope we can mutual answer each other. First to directly answer your question, I think it depends very much on the load that your app has to handle. If you have to scale your app to many resource servers, keeping a separate auth server is the best because you can centrally manage user credentials and access_token in one place.

Here is my question. I believe if you have tried something similar to mine, you can give me some suggestions.

[OAuth - Separating Auth Server and Resource server returns invalid token when accessing protected resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572208/oauth-separating-auth-server-and-resource-server-returns-invalid-token-when-ac?s=5|0.0000)

Comment: Each Resource Server has to talk to a Authentication Server on every resource access. If we keep them separate they'll  need to talk via http (probably). If we keep them together they'll just connect directly to the same database.